# SPNEGO/Kerberos No credential found error with requests from Linux client

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, kerberos, spnego

I am currently implementing a single signon solution for a customer that is based on Java, Tomcat and Kerberos. 
Users are to access the URL of an intranet Tomcat application from their client browsers, the Tomcat application acquires the users' credentials via Kerberos and redirects them to the actual web application.
Our customer's environment is a typical mixture of a Windows AD server acting as the KDC and Linux Tomcat application servers. The SSO functionality is supposed to be used from both Windows and Linux clients. This is what appears to be different from most answers I can find on the net where people have Linux web application servers but only use Windows clients.

Now, in my local setup I get some strange behaviour. My development environment is a Tomcat 7.0.26 running from MyEclipse 8.6 under Windows 7. My test environment is a Tomcat 7.0.26 or 7.0.53 behind an Apache web server on a Centos 6 machine. I have set up the AD server correctly, generated the necessary keytab files etc. and everything is running smoothly in the development environment. I can access the Tomcat application from both Linux and Windows clients using IE and Firefox, Kerberos authentication proceeds and I get redirected properly.

When deploying the Tomcat application on the test server this keeps working when trying to sign on from Windows clients. However, when I try to access the test server from a Linux client (I have tried from Linux Mint 13 and Ubuntu 13.10), I get the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: No credential found for: 1.3.6.1.5.2.51.3.6.1.5.2.5 usage: Accept
>       net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:233)

I have to admit that I do not properly understand this message. Does it point to a problem with the credentials supplied by the client or a problem with the application server negotiating with the KDC? I have done some research on this problem and have found out that the indicated oid 1.3.6.1.5.2.5 stands for GSS_IAKERB_MECHANISM and not GSS_KRB5_MECHANISM or GSS_SPNEGO_MECHANISM which I find strange. Also, nobody else appears to have exactly the same problem.

I have tried switching from MIT Kerberos to Heimdal Kerberos and back. I have tried Firefox and Chromium, on the application server I have switched between Tomcat 7.0.26 and 7.0.53, the problem still persists. I am using the latest spnego.jar.

Now: Calls from Linux to the Tomcat running on the Windows development machine succeed and calls from Linux clients to the Linux application server fail with the same error message for both browsers tried.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GSS_IAKERB_MECHANISM` means that the client is not able to determine the realm/kdc to create a service ticket and asks the server to serve as an intermediate to the target KDC. Check Wireshark traffic. Your task now is to analyze why the client is not able to create a service ticket for that SPN. I have observed this issue on Heimdal on FreeBSD with Microsoft KDC.

So the problem ist not your Tomcat instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply (even though it seemed very cryptic at first). I did some more research and I also employed Wireshark for the first time (proeviously I had only used tcpdump) - very revealing. The problem turned out to be caused by some defective reverse DNS mapping. When asking for the service ticket, my client's GSSAPI-lib obtained the IP of the service, obtained the reverse mapping for the IP and used the result for obtaining the ticket. And as the result was wrong, the KDC denied the service ticket.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You should know that SSPI is actually not performing reverse DNS lookup but relies that the SPN matches the `CNAME` record. I, personally, have disabled reverse DNS lookups in MIT/Heimdal Kerberos. Please note that the DNS entries must not necessary but incorrect. If you have a canonical name for a service run on server phys. machines but under one hostname, you'll need a service account for that in here reverse lookups do not simply work.